# Adding UIView to UIButton subview prevents touch events

Tags: iphone, uibutton, handle, touches, addsubview

I'm trying to add a view as a button's subview like this (`btn1` is a `UIButton`);

```
[self.btn1 addSubview:view1];
```

After adding it, the button wont give any touch related events, the button works fine without this subview added.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The touch events always come to the view on top, unless if has disabled interaction.

What you should do is:

```
view1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```